# Register Taxonomy - What is `query_var`?

Tags: wp-query, register-taxonomy

[The Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) doesn't really explain it very well, what is it used for and how do I use it exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is explained pretty thoroughly in the Codex, in my opinion. It serves a purpose e.g. when you want to grab posts for your taxonomy, it is a URL slug for your taxonomy, e.g. `example.com/tag/cats` -> `example.com/query_var/cats`.

> Note: The query_var is used for direct queries through `WP_Query` like

```
new WP_Query( array( 'people' => $person_name ) )
```

> and URL queries like `/?people=$person_name`. Setting `query_var` to `false` will disable these methods, but you can still fetch posts with an explicit `WP_Query` taxonomy query like

```
WP_Query(array('taxonomy'=>'people', 'term'=>$person_name)).
```

Basically, `query_var` is part of [the WordPress Query Vars](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars).